# "Ends in" or "ends with" a phone call

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was writing a question on Security.SE and couldn't figure out which pronoun was actually correct in the sentence:

> This [process] always ends **with/in** a phone call.

The intended meaning is that because of certain policies, the end result of a process is a phone call (to me).

Which preposition is correct here, and why? If they are interchangeable, why?

PS - I'm asking on ELL.SE because I would like to know how to explain this to my French ELL students in the future. Prepositions are notoriously difficult to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Ends with**" is usually used when you are pointing to a *known* or *expected* conclusion to something, and the ending is normally part of the subject, for example:

> - The show ended with a song.
> - The story ended with a twist.

The song is part of the show, and the twist is part of the story. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ended%20with%20a%20song%2Cended%20in%20a%20song&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cended%20with%20a%20song%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cended%20in%20a%20song%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cended%20with%20a%20song%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cended%20in%20a%20song%3B%2Cc0) supports this.

"**Ends in**" is normally used when pointing to the *result* of something, for example:

> - The day ended in tears
> - The marriage ended in divorce

These are not expected endings, nor part of the subject. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ended%20in%20divorce%2C%20ended%20with%20divorce&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cended%20in%20divorce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cended%20with%20divorce%3B%2Cc0) supports this.

For this reason, I think your example requires "with":

> This process always ends with a phone call.

The call is expected, and is part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is rather difficult to give definitive answers on prepositions. The answer is generally what everyone habitually uses in a particular context rather than a clear set of rules, and the habit change over time too.

Personally I would say 'ends with a phone call', and that most things are  ..'with' a phone call or 'by' a phone call. E.g. Solved with a phone call, Ordered with a phone call, etc.

'In' a phone call fits better when it's something that happened during that call eg. 'I asked in a phone call', as opposed to something which results with or was a result of, a phone call. However some people would indeed say ends in a phone call, so it's not wrong really, and probably more a case of local variations of English usage.

I hope these examples give you an idea of how those prepositions commonly used, which is the probably the best way to explain them - empirically.

Comment: My first thought was if I hear that *something always ends in X*, my ***default*** assumption would be to interpret it through the "lens" of *Y always ends **up** in X* (and ***It'll all end in tears**,* obviously) - which particular construction I strongly associate with contexts where that means *action Y is futile, since it always results in the **undesirable** end state X*.

Comment: And I suppose there's certain amount of contextual influence as to whether there's a correlation, or a cause and effect relationship. Does an evening end with dinner, or end in dinner? Tears and disasters usually being an effect, where as dinner and phone calls more of a correlation?